# SerializationException and IOException: Sharing violation on path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the following two errors when trying to create a save and load system for my game..

> "SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour in assembly UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not marked as serializable.
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers (System.Type type, StreamingContext context) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization/FormatterServices.cs:101)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.CodeGenerator.GenerateMetadataTypeInternal (System.Type type, StreamingContext context) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/CodeGenerator.cs:78)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.CodeGenerator.GenerateMetadataType (System.Type type, StreamingContext context) (at

and

> IOException: Sharing violation on path 
>       C:\Users\Sam\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany\Game\test.txt
>       System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320)
>       System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode)
>       (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode)
>       SaveSystem.SavePlayer (.Player player) (at Assets/Scripts/SaveSystem.cs:22)
>       Player.SavePlayer () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:47)
>       Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:13)

Here is the save and load method
Savesystem class below

```
public static class SaveSystem {
public static void SavePlayer (Player player){
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/test.fun";
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);
    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    stream.Close();
}

public static PlayerData LoadPlayer() {
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/test.fun";

    if (File.Exists(path)){
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
        stream.Close();

        return data;

    } else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Any help given is very appreciated

Comment: Well a sharing violation says the file is open, either it didnt close correctly last time, or, is open in something else.. It is odd to put a binary bunch of data in a text file

Comment: Hello..I have closed everything and run the unity file but I receive the same error. I have also changed the text file to save as xml.

Comment: Whilst I can see no obvious problem with the code above, I suspect you have _other_ code that is attempting to read the same file.  Please post that code and how both methods are being called

Comment: Hi I have a load method that reads the file. I have updated the code :)

Comment: Thanks.  1) you do know that one method is using _"test.txt"_ whilst another _"test.xml"_?  2) it shouldn't be called .xml anyway because you are not saving as XML but rather binary 3) how are these methods being called? Show us how they are called from the behaviour.  4) are you using threads?

Comment: Btw now you've added the first error about unable to serialize, it means its not closing the file, because it barfed

Comment: MickyD - 1) Sorry that was a mistake.. Ive saved them both as .fun now..thanks. 3) I have added the other classes to the code. 4) sorry..im not sure what you mean by threads

Comment: BugFinder - Thats the first error I get when trying to save it, when I press save again i get sharing violation.. does stream.Close() not help close the file ? :)

Comment: nope, if it barfed it doesnt continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some working code for you to try, I tried to make it as easy to edit as i could, so you can make it work for your use case.

`Edit:` You need to create the folder SaveData in Assets else it doesn't work, but it will tell you that in the debug log too.

```
public void SavePlayerData()
{
    // Create the folder path.
    string t_Path = "Assets/SaveData";
    // Specify the file name.
    string t_FileName = "save.txt";

    if( AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder( t_Path ) )
    {
        Debug.Log( "Found: " + t_Path );

        // Create the file path.
        t_FileName = t_Path + "/" + t_FileName;

        if ( AssetDatabase.FindAssets( "save.txt" ).Length > 0)
        {
            // Create the actual text file.
            TextAsset t_NewFile = new TextAsset( "" );
            AssetDatabase.CreateAsset( t_NewFile, t_FileName );
        }          

        // Add text to the created file:
        string t_CopyRight = "" +
        "//////////////////////////////////////  \n" +
        "//    This save file is created     //  \n" +
        "//                by                //  \n" +              // Copyright text.
        "//               Livo               //  \n" +
        "//////////////////////////////////////  \n" +
        " \n";

        string t_Text = "This is the frist text value";             // Random PlayerSaveData text.
        string t_DiffrentText = "This is the second text value";    // Random Level text.
        string t_Location = "x=100,y=0,z=250";                      // Random Transform.position text.
        // You can add your playerdata to these strings.

        t_FileName = t_FileName.Replace( "Assets", "" );
        File.WriteAllText( Application.dataPath + t_FileName,   t_CopyRight + "\n" +
                                                                "[PlayerSaveData]\n" + t_Text + "\n\n" +
                                                                "[Level]\n" + t_DiffrentText + "\n\n" +
                                                                "[Location]\n" + t_Location );
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets( );
        AssetDatabase.Refresh( );
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log( "There is no folder with that name: " + t_Path );
    }
}
```

This is how you can import your save data:

```
public void LoadPlayerData()
{
    string t_Path = "Assets/SaveData/save.txt";

    //Read the text from directly from the test.txt file
    StreamReader t_Reader = new StreamReader( t_Path );
    Debug.Log( t_Reader.ReadToEnd( ) );
    t_Reader.Close( );
}
```

BTW: The code overrides the save data each run, but i'd say that is what you want with a save file. If you want different save files, just dynamically give a new name to the `t_FileName`

Comment: What do you mean? You create new text and it does not override the current one?

Comment: When I change some content and run the same script, the file contents do change for me, maybe you made a mistake somewhere. Also I added a few new lines, so that if the asset already exists it just put the new text in, instead of recreating the whole asset.

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't show the code of Player Data. I think you also made a error as me. You forgot to write [Serializable] and include using System. May this work for you as me